# Double Click Python File to Run Program

Tags: python-3.x

I’ve searched and read many posts but none actually describe what I would like to do.  Using Debian Stretch, I’ve been trying to create a Python 3 program that runs what would otherwise be a typed command with switches at the gnome terminal.  This is how it should run:

1. Double click the created *.py file that contains the code for the program.
2. The gnome terminal appears and the command/switches appear after the $ and then the program runs.  Some of the switches have zeros (0) which seems to present an issue.  Example command:

$ ./binary.bin -j 0 -n 1300

Anyone have any ideas on how I should start to write this program?  Any suggestions would be helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: you could create an intermediate bash file that runs your program with the specific arguments like 'run_program.sh' if you can't figure out another way

Comment: If you are on Windows platform you can create .exe of *.py file